# Error while sending picture to webserver in android

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I've been having trouble with this part of my app, this is my first app so I use tutorials for every part.
On this activity I need to allow the user to take a new picture and send it to my webserver. But it has a fatal error in the onActivityResult()...

The error is at this line:

```
Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
```

Here's the code where it stops working:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (true) {
            //requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK

            selectedImage = data.getData();
            photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            // Cursor to get image uri to display
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            //ERROR
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.Imageprev);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
        }
    }
```

This is the code that runs before it:

```
 Button btpic, btnup;
    private Uri fileUri;
    String picturePath;
    Uri selectedImage;
    Bitmap photo;
    String ba1;
    public static String URL = "http://192.168.1.11/CarQuiz/images/";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.acticity_camera);


        btpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cpic);
        btpic.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clickpic();
            }
        });

        btnup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.up);
        btnup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                upload();
            }
        });
    }
```

And the function for the camera:

```
  private void clickpic() {
        // Check Camera
        if (getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(

                PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            // Open default camera

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

            // start the image capture Intent
            startActivityForResult(intent, 100);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "Camera not supported", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

This is the last thing in the logcat:

```
    05-16 12:45:57.027    5928-5928/com.XXXXX.YYYYY.carquizXXXX E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        Process: com.XXXXX.XXXXX.carquizXXXXX, PID: 5928
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=100, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.XXXXXX.YYYYY.carquizXXXXX/com.XXXXX.
YYYYYYYe.carquizCCCCC.Camera}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3539)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
         Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getScheme()' on a null object reference
                at android.content.ContentResolver.acquireUnstableProvider(ContentResolver.java:1437)
                at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:462)
                at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:422)
                at com.helsen.yenthe.carquizhelsen.Camera.onActivityResult(Camera.java:118)
                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3535)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3582)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:144)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

I used this tutorial to create this: https://trinitytuts.com/capture-image-upload-server-android/

I'm stuck at this for a few houres now, thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: And what is the error? Post your logcat output.

Comment: I placed it in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do this is to implement an IntentService and notify status with broadcast intents. please checkout complete code from github

Android library that provides an easy to use service to upload files with Android Notification Center integration

https://github.com/alexbbb/android-upload-service

Android Uploading Camera Image, Video to Server with Progress Bar

http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/android-uploading-camera-image-video-to-server-with-progress-bar/

//used this to get bitmap

```
File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
            for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
                if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
                    f = temp;
                    break;
                }
            }
            Bitmap bm;
            BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), btmapOptions);

            if (bm != null)
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

let me know if you facing any problem to integrate this code

Comment: How can I upload the image from the camerafunction with this? How can I convert it in a bitmap?

Comment: File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
    for (File temp : f.listFiles()) {
     if (temp.getName().equals("temp.jpg")) {
      f = temp;
      break;
     }
    }
    Bitmap bm;
    BitmapFactory.Options btmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileUri.getPath(), btmapOptions);

    if (bm != null)
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

Comment: Okay, I'll try to put everything together, I'll keep you updated.

Comment: please check my updated answer. if your issue still not fixed.then provide your email id so i can provide you complete working code

Comment: if you get your answer please mark my answer as a correct.@Yenthe Helsen

Comment: Yea your answer helped me alot, thank you! It just took me a pretty long time to get rid of all the other errors. @SahirSaiyed